# How to create a break in a numbered list in HTML

Tags: html, list, numbered, numbered-list

I am looking to create an alphabetized numbered list (which is fairly easy), however I am looking to add a break in the numbers for a place to add the letters (A, B, C, etc) however keep the chronology of the numbers.

I know that I could do the numbering myself and have no issue, however I want the numbers to automatically adjust as I add items. Hopefully someone can tell me how to do this in HTML.

Essentially this is what I would like it to look like:

**A**

1. Air Force One
2. Aladdin
3. Amazing Spider-Man

**B**

4. Back to the Future
5. Batman Returns
6. Beverly Hills Cop

**C**

7. Club Paradise

Comment: I believe this will work: <ol start="4"></ol> That would be for the second list.

Comment: why not try the following (with empty li)      `<ol type="A">
    <li></li>
    <ol>
    <li>2nd line</li>
    </ol>
    <li></li>
    </ol>` with the comment from @rrd this should work

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `start` attribute of the `ol` tag, like this:

```html
<h2>A</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Air Force One</li>
  <li>Aladdin</li>
  <li>Amazing Spider-Man</li>
</ol>

<h2>B</h2>
<ol start="4">
  <li>Back to the Future</li>
  <li>Batman Returns</li>
  <li>Beverly Hills Cop</li>
</ol>

<h2>C</h2>
<ol start="7">
  <li>Club Paradise</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

following code should do the trick without JS:

```css
ol.start { 
    counter-reset: mycounter; 
}
ol.start li, ol.continue li {
    list-style: none;
}
ol.start li:before, ol.continue li:before { 
    content: counter(mycounter) ") "; 
    counter-increment: mycounter;
    position:relative;
    text-align: right;
    width:25px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    left:-30px;
}
```

```html
  <ol type="A">
    <li></li>
    <ol class='start'>
    <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
    </ol>
    <li></li>
    <ol  class='continue'>
    <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
    </ol>
      <li></li>
    <ol  class='continue'>
    <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
      <li>2nd line</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
  var entityAlpha = 65;
 $('li').each(function(i,e){
   if(i%3 === 0){
     $(this).css('position', 'relative');
     $(this).append('<span class="alpha">&#'+entityAlpha+';</span>');
     entityAlpha = entityAlpha+1;
   }
 });
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

ol li:nth-child(3n){
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
.alpha{
  left:-25px;
  top:-30px;
  position:absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol{
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
       <li> Air Force One</li>
        <li>Aladdin</li>
        <li>Amazing Spider-Man</li>
        <li>Back to the Future</li>
        <li>Batman Returns</li>
        <li>Beverly Hills Cop</li>
        <li>Club Paradise</li>
    </ol>
```